# Reading data from Database and then filter data on some condition in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, linq-to-sql, dataset, sqldataadapter

My question is what is the best way to fetch data from SQL Server in Code Behind(Using Query) and then apply filtering on some parameters in Code Behind(C#)

Like I have to fetch data from SQL Server with Dynamic Query - [TableName] should be passed as per input

```
Select * From [TableName]
```

And then i want to apply filtering on the result like applying effective date filtering, isActive or anything..

```
string SqlString = "SELECT * FROM TableName;";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, Conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    Conn.Open();
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
catch (SqlException se)
{
    DBErLog.DbServLog(se, se.ToString());
}
finally
{
    Conn.Close();
}
```

or i would use

```
DataSet ds = new DatSet()
sda.Fill(ds)
```

How to iterate to the resultset(DataTable/DataSet) and filter records if we did not know the Table Columns(Except Effective Date or IsActive column)

Then Create object and convert the object in XML form as a result.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `DataTable` or `DatSet` are almost equivalent. When you fill a `DataTable`, it automatically creates a `DatSet` for you and creates the table inside. Similarly, when you fill a `DatSet`, it automatically creates a table inside.

Comment: For the replacing stuff in a String part: `Use String.Format(string, value1, value2, etc)`. E.g.  `String s = String.Format("Hello {0}", "world");` For the iteration part: you can count the columns and the rows and you can even get the headers. Every DataSet has n DataTables and there you have the columns.

Comment: You can use your approach of creating a `DatSet` and use Linq to SQL to manipulate it. That's OK for very tiny projects. However, for most real world projects, it is always better to create your data object classes and then fill them with the data coming from your database. Then you can use Linq to objects to manipulate them.

Comment: If you are able to filter using an appropriate WHERE clause then do it on the database. It is always faster than retrieving the whole data through a network connection and then processing that data on the client side

Comment: @Steve That's generally the case and a good advice, but not **always**. For example, if it is a desktop app and you're using all the data, but just want to present it in different ways depending on user selection, then it can be better to do this kind of processing on the client side. I'm not complaining about your comment (I upvoted it), but only about the word **always** :-)

Comment: if you have a *where* condition is the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Steve mentioned in his comment, a good practice is to filter as much as you can inside your SQL query.
 
 there are multiple ways to filter and manipulate your data using [T-sql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/) conditions (`WHERE`,`GROUP BY`, `HAVING` etc). SQL server is very efficient compared to the manipulations you can do inside your application.
 here is an interesting discussion about this topic: [“Never do in code what you can get the SQL server to do well for you” - Is this a recipe for a bad design?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/never-do-in-code-what-you-can-get-the-sql-server-to-do-well-for-you-is-this)

on the other hand, there are exceptional cases where using sql steatments will be a lost of resources and unnecessary. for example High Frequency GUI changes and updates, When you encounter a case like that, multiple queries against sql server probably will be a waste of resources, in that case one way to cope is to extract data from a datatable or some other object that is cached inside your program using [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq), [Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), binary search etc...
**It is important to note that as a programmer you should master and understand what is the most efficient way to manipulate data.**

please see my comments/advises inside your code:

```
private void foo()
{
    // add a much conditions as you can inside the query
    // for example "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL AND col2 LIKE '%jr%' AND col3 > 3 AND YEAR(col4) = 2017"...
    string SqlString = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, Conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        // you can add more conditions, filterring, sorting, grouping using LINQ or Lambda Expretions
        // for example create new datatable based on condition
        DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("col3") > 3).Select(y => y).CopyToDataTable();

        // use WriteToXml() method and save as xml file
        string FilePath = @"C:\YOUR_FILE_PATH.xml";
        // give name to the datatable, WriteToXml() can not create xml with null table name
        newDt.TableName = "myTableName";
        // save
        newDt.WriteXml(FilePath);

    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        DBErLog.DbServLog(se, se.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Conn.Close();
    }
}
```